# How to find the source of ora-01031 insufficient privileges when executing a test on a ref cursor with utPLSQL?

Tags: unit-testing, plsql

I'm doing research on unit testing in PLSQL. I set up a test database with some tables and packages with functions and procedures. Currently I'm giving the test framework 'utPLSQL' a try but stumbled upon an error when testing on a ref cursor. I can run all of my tests but the result of the test on the ref cursor says "ora-01031 insufficient privileges", that's all I get. How can I find the source of this error? Or does anyone encountered the same problem? The installation of utPLSQL was successful and all the other functionality of the test framework works.

This is the procedure I want to test:

```
FUNCTION F_Get_Customers_RefCurs(P_LASTNAME IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN cust_refcur
IS
cust_result cust_refcur;
BEGIN
  OPEN cust_result FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMERS
    WHERE LASTNAME = P_LASTNAME
    ORDER BY email ASC;
  return(cust_result);
END F_Get_Customers_RefCurs;
```

I have declared cust_refcur in the spec of the package which contains my function as following:

```
TYPE cust_refcur IS REF CURSOR;
```

And this is the test:

```
PROCEDURE ut_F_Get_Customers_RefCurs
IS
params utplsql_util.utplsql_params;
BEGIN
  utPLSQL_Util.reg_In_Param (1,
                           'Tester',
                           params);
  UTASSERT.eq_refc_query ('Get customers on last name is successful (refcursor)',
                        'PK_ORDERS.F_GET_CUSTOMERS_REFCURS',
                        params,
                        0,
                        'SELECT customerid, firstname, lastname, email, password
                         FROM CUSTOMERS
                         WHERE LASTNAME = ''Tester''
                         ORDER BY email ASC');
END;
```

Comment: Have you created your procedures in the same schema as the utPLSQL packages? Or are you using a different schema?

Comment: I have created my tables and packages in another schema because I don't want to mix up my own packages and tables with the ones the test framework creates.

Comment: Could you add the declaration for cust_refcur, please?

Comment: I've added the declaration.

Comment: Which version of utPLSQL are you using? 2.2 from utplsql.sourceforge.net?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm using version 2.2.

Comment: One more question: How do you run your test? If I run it with 
begin
  pk_ut_orders.ut_f_get_customers_refcurs;
end;
I get a "PLS-00221: 'F_GET_CUSTOMERS_REFCURS' is not a procedure or is undefined"

Comment: I always run my test with SQLplus. I connect to the scheme where the procedure is located en then I type the command: exec utplsql.test('name of the package')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried getting your example to work, but unfortunately, I got weird errors from utPLSQL.

Since the last version of utPLSQL on Sourceforge is from 2005 and Steven Feuerstein is now working on a commercial product that essentially does the same, I'd recommend looking into other solutions for unit testing your PL/SQL code - some links:

- Oracle SQL Developer has some [built-in unit test-functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35137_01/appdev.32/e35117/unit_testing.htm#BCGHEHFE), and it's free
- there's also [Quest code tester](http://www.quest.com/toad-development-suite-for-oracle/code-tester-for-oracle.aspx) (this one's commercial)

Comment: Thanks for the effort Frank! I've also got weird errors when I was working with utPLSQL. I know that Steven developed Quest Code Tester, I have tested this already and it worked like a charm. But I evaluated utPLSQL also because I'm doing research as part of my internship at a company.

Answer (score 0):

maybe cause by 'RETURN cust_refcur',the type use by utplsql is store in varchar2(10) ,
try 'return refcur' ?
-zhaozb

Comment: Could you expand on that a little?

Answer (score 0):

When running this assertion (`eq_refc_query`), utPLSQL needs to temporarily create a table. It does this by using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` which requires that the user have the `CREATE TABLE` privilege granted to them directly, rather than via a role.

[Full disclosure: I am one of the administrators of the utPLSQL project]